# Mac OS X GNU Make default parameters

Tags: macos, mac, make

Is there any way to set system or user wide that make always uses -j3 parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do

```
alias make="/usr/bin/make -j3"
```

Comment: That will work only in shell, it may not work in IDE like QtCreator but it's one of options. I thought gnumake has some kind of config file

Comment: OK - have you tried setting CFLAGS to "-j3"?

Comment: It is not compiler flag

Answer (score 1):

Create a script named `make` that calls the real make with -j3 and then the other command line parameters.  Modify your path so the script is found before the real make, or you could rename the real make to `/usr/bin/make.real` and place your script in `/usr/bin`.